# Remove word from string based on matching item in array

Tags: sql, google-bigquery

I have this table:

[image: Big Query Table]

Assume that "florio" is a city contained somewhere in the AllLocationTerms array column.

How do I remove "florio" when it exists on my list of locations in AllLocationTerms array column?

Basically, I want to remove all matching items in AllLocationTerms from "Query" column.

It can happen that there are 2 or more words - "new york apartments" as Query and "new", "york" in the array. The outcome should be "apartments" in this case.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Below is to address use case like yours when you need to check 800,000 rows against the location list array which has around 40k items
So, 40K items are definitely too much for being used to construct regular expression as it is in my previous answer.
So, to address this, I propose to rather split your query string into separate words preserving position number - then exclude those which are terms by left joining and finally assemble the survived words back to string

```sql
#standardSQL
WITH `project.dataset.table` AS (
  SELECT 'florio management apartments' query, 1 clicks, ['battle','creek','iowa','florio'] allLocationTerms UNION ALL
  SELECT 'florio creek management iowa apartments' query, 1 clicks, ['battle','creek','iowa','florio'] allLocationTerms 
)
SELECT *,
  (
    SELECT STRING_AGG(word, ' ' ORDER BY pos) 
    FROM (
      SELECT word, MIN(pos) pos 
      FROM UNNEST(SPLIT(query, ' ')) word WITH OFFSET AS pos
      LEFT JOIN UNNEST(allLocationTerms) term 
      ON word = term
      GROUP BY word
      HAVING COUNT(DISTINCT term) = 0
    )
  ) modified_query
FROM `project.dataset.table`
```

Comment: Ok, I will test this one.

The previous query timed out after 6 hours.

DZ

Comment: 6 hours makes sense because it is bigquery timeout. let's see how this one will work for you :o)

Comment: Seems like it's working and it takes about an hour to complete. 
Thank you :)

Comment: Consider voting up this answer too!

Answer (score 2):

Below is for BigQuery Standard SQL

```sql
#standardSQL
SELECT *, 
  REGEXP_REPLACE(query, 
    (SELECT CONCAT('\\b', STRING_AGG(term, '\\b|\\b'), '\\b') FROM UNNEST(allLocationTerms) term),
  '') modified_query
FROM `project.dataset.table`
```

you can test, play with above using dummy data as below

```sql
#standardSQL
WITH `project.dataset.table` AS (
  SELECT 'florio management apartments' query, 1 clicks, ['battle','creek','iowa','florio'] allLocationTerms UNION ALL
  SELECT 'florio creek management iowa apartments' query, 1 clicks, ['battle','creek','iowa','florio'] allLocationTerms 
)
SELECT *, 
  REGEXP_REPLACE(query, 
    (SELECT CONCAT('\\b', STRING_AGG(term, '\\b|\\b'), '\\b') FROM UNNEST(allLocationTerms) term),
  '') modified_query
FROM `project.dataset.table`
```

result is

```sql
Row query                              clicks   allLocationTerms    modified_query   
1   florio management apartments            1   battle              management apartments    
                                                creek        
                                                iowa         
                                                florio       
2   florio creek management iowa apartments 1   battle              management apartments    
                                                creek        
                                                iowa         
                                                florio
```

Comment: Actually one more question.

I am trying to check 800,000 rows against this location list array which has around 40k items.

The query has been now running for 20 minutes and I have no clue when it's gonna end.

Is there any room for optimization?

Comment: I think - yes - we can try. i will update my answer with another solution. stay tuned :o) even though 40K items in terms array sounds no, but we can try  good

Comment: it really make sense having in mind your 40K items in array. as I promised - I will follow up with another approach that might or might now help - but at least yo will try. stay tuned  - i will get to this later in a day

Comment: @DanielZrůst - check my second answer - i added it as a new answer as it is totally new one as opposed to modified or optimized version of my first answer. Note: it has assumption about `space` being a delimiter. I think it should handle your 40K. Try and let me know. please comment under respective answer :o) and is this one still running?